# NLP: TypeError: reduce expected at least 2 arguments, got 1

Tags: python, function, methods, typeerror, text-segmentation

```
import math, functools

def splitPairs(word):
   return [(word[:i+1], word[i+1:]) for i in range(len(word))]

def segment(word):
   if not word: return []
   allSegmentations = [[first] + segment(rest)
                       for (first, rest) in splitPairs(word)]
   return max(allSegmentations, key = wordSegFitness)

class OneGramDist(dict):
    def __init__(self):
        self.gramCount = 0
        for line in open('Norvig Word Library.txt'):
            (word, count) = line[:-1].split('\t')
            self[word] = int(count)
            self.gramCount += self[word]

    def __call__(self, word):
        if word in self:
            return float(self[word]) / self.gramCount
        else:
            return 1.0/ self.gramCount

singleWordProb = OneGramDist()

def wordSegFitness(words):
    return functools.reduce(lambda x,y: x+y),
    (math.log10(singleWordProblem(w)) for w in words)
```

I'm trying to improve the word segmentation of some text files I have. Some of the words in these files are joined (e.g. `'howmuchdoesthecarcost` or `'helloworld'`), and I'm running a Naive Bayesian process to segment the words apart.

However, when I run something like `segment("helloworld")`, I get the following error: `TypeError: reduce expected at least 2 arguments, got 1`. How can I change the arguments in reduce without losing the efficacy of `wordSegFitness()`?

Comment: Did you mean `return functools.reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, (long generator expression)),`? Seems to be just a mismatched `)` (right now, you return a one-tuple of `reduce` with too few parameters and then ("after" the return) create a generator without using it...

Comment: TBH, this isn't my code.. I'm just a statistician looking to clean up some words. Do I need to pass along two arguments with `segment()`? I can't delete the `math.log10...` part, because that's an essential part of the Bayesian model.

Comment: No, you have to change the last line to `return functools.reduce(lambda x,y: x+y,
    (math.log10(singleWordProblem(w)) for w in words))`

Comment: Thank you. I also had to resolve a naming error with `singleWordProb` != `singleWordProblem`. It runs like a charm now.